# Simple method of allocating exact amount of RAM

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a function that makes my application allocate X RAM for Y seconds
(I know theres 1.2GB limit on objects).

Is there better way than this?

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
public void TakeRam(int X, int Y)
{
    Byte[] doubleArray = new Byte[X];
    System.Threading.Sleep(Y*60)
    return
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the effects to be? On the same process or on the system? You are allocating virtual RAM. And btw, Sleep() is in milliseconds.

Comment: yes. extacly. I need to simulate a situation where my process takes too much ram.

Comment: "takes memory" is surprisingly complicated on a modern OS. The fact that your App uses some amount of RAM doesn't mean that another process cannot use it at the same time.

Comment: thats totally OK for my test. I am testing the systems memory leak detection service..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would prefer to use unmanaged memory, like this:

```
IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(X);
Sleep(Y);
Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(p);
```

Otherwise the CLR garbage collector may play tricks on you.

Comment: should I use [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
 ? isn't there a chance it will be optimized?

Comment: why AllocCoTaskMem and not AllocHGlobal?

Comment: Considering NoOptimization: no, you do not need this if you use unmanaged memory allocation. .NET can only optimize methods if it knows how they behave. When you call unmanaged function, .NET does not know how it behaves and has to execute code to keep the call sequence exactly as you write it.

Comment: @ironic - both are valid for that matter indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you write to memory it will not get allocated. Doing repeated garbage collections does not lower the memory usage significantly. The program grows to 1,176,272K with garbage collection, and 1,176,312 K without garbage collection; with this line commented out: `GC.GetTotalMemory(true);` When this line is commented out `byteArray[i] = 99;` the program grows to 4,464K

1. Changed the name of the array; it doesn't hold doubles.
2. Changed it to write to the memory
3. Changed the name of the sleep function.

You can see in Task Manager that the memory gets allocated to the running process:

This works:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace NewTest
{
    class ProgramA
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TakeRam(1200000000, 3000000);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
        static public void TakeRam(long X, int Y)
        {
            Byte[] byteArray = new Byte[X];
            for (int i = 0; i < X; i += 4096)
            {
                GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
                byteArray[i] = 99;
            }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source for the second claim?  I am surprised that's the case!

Comment: It looks like it's not allocated until the respective 4KB chunk is written to.  For example, this produces the same result: `for (int i = 0; i < X; i += 4096)` but not this: `for (int i = 0; i < X; i += 8192)`

Comment: Wow, you have a serious attitude problem.  It's perfectly reasonable to ask for an official source or reference for something counter-intuitive.  Why not be helpful and share it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to `KeepAlive` your block of memory, otherwise the GC can deallocate it. I would even fill the memory (so that you are sure the memory was really allocated, and not reserved)

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
public void TakeRam(int X, int Y)
{
    Byte[] doubleArray = new Byte[X];

    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
    {
        doubleArray[i] = 0xFF;
    }

    System.Threading.Sleep(Y)
    GC.KeepAlive(doubleArray);
}
```

I'll add that, at 64bits, the maximum size of an array is something less than 2GB, not 1.2GB.

Comment: Maximum object size changed a little since .NET 4.5. Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ironic Thanks... I didn't know. The maximum number of elements is still the same, but if you use `double` or `Guid` or `KeyValuePair<Guid, Guid>` you can use much more memory :-) (the KVP is a `struct`, so are `Guid`)